# Mocking/stubbing objects that are only defined in a closure

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, chai

First of all, for testing my library, I'm using Mocha and Chai, but I'm probably going to need  Sinon too sometime.

This is the library:

```
import Service from 'service'; // a third-party module out of my control

const service = Service(...);

class MyLib {
    ... uses `service` in a bunch of different ways ...
    ... service.put(foo) ...
    ... service.get(bar) ...
}

export default MyLib;
```

This is basically the test file:

```
import MyLib from '../my-lib.js';

describe('MyLib', () => {
    describe('a method that uses the service', () => {
        ...
```

The `service` object makes some calls to remote servers, which I can't really do in the tests. Therefore, I'm thinking I should stub the service's methods or mock the entire service object. However, since the object is constant and only reachable through the `MyLib` closure, I don't know how.

Ideally I don't wish to change the API of `MyLib` to e.g. inject the service object in the constructor.

I use Babel 6 with the `es2015` preset, if it matters.

How should I approach this?

Comment: You may try to mock your `service` via [Mockery](https://sazzer.github.io/blog/2015/08/20/Unit-Testing-ES6-Modules-Mockery/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it.

### The simplest way without extra libraries

Save service as a class property and call it from there:

```
import Service from 'service'; 

const service = Service(...);

class MyLib {
    constructor() {
       this.service = service;
    }
    ... now you should call service in a bit different way
    ... this.service.put(foo) ...
    ... this.service.get(bar) ...
}

export default MyLib;
```

Then you can rewrite service instance in your tests:

```
it('should call my mock', () => {
   const lib = new MyLib();
   lib.service = mockedService; // you need to setup this mock, with Sinon, for example
   lib.doSomething();
   assert.ok(mockedService.put.calledOnce); // works
});
```

### Mock require() function

There are some libraries that allow you to override results of `require()` function. My favourite one is [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire/). You can use it and your module will get mockedSerice instead of real:

```
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';

it('should call my mock', () => {
   const MyLib = proxyquire('./my-lib', {
     // pass here the map of mocked imports
     service: mockedService
   })
   const lib = new MyLib();
   lib.doSomething();
   assert.ok(mockedService.put.calledOnce); // works
});
```

### Use `rewire` to get access into module closure

[Rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) is a special library that instruments module code so then you can change any local variable there

```
import rewire from 'rewire';

it('should call my mock', () => {
   const MyLib = rewire('./my-lib')
   const lib = new MyLib();

   // __set__ is a special secret method added by rewire
   MyLib.__set__('service', mockedService);

   lib.doSomething();
   assert.ok(mockedService.put.calledOnce); // works
});
```

Also, there is a [babel-plugin-rewire](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire) for better integration with your tools.

All methods above are nice you may pick that seems better for your issue.

Comment: this was comprehensive and awesome. i appreciated all the techniques you shared, because I can start out testing with the first approach for simplicity of testing, and then migrate to the other ones for a better coding style

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same thing recently.
You can take advantage of https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching
In the test you are writing, require/import the service the same way you do in the file you are testing.
Then use Sinon to stub the methods you are using within the file to test.

```
sinon.stub(Service, put).returns()
```

When the file requires the service, it will use the modified module.

I haven't tested your exact case, where you are creating instance of the service and only after that you work with it, but a bit of playing with it should help you achieve what you want, and it is all without any external libraries, only simple sinon stub.

Answer (score 0):

Your tests for `MyLib` shouldn't test `service`, so I would suggest mocking all or most of it. You should just check that `MyLib` is calling the right functions on `service` with the right arguments.

I'm not sure about sinon, but that looks like a pretty standard way to import and use a library, I would be surprised if it doesn't support mocking `service`.

Comment: I agree about the approach you are suggesting, but the problem is that `service` is only reachable by `MyLib` because they share the same closure. Therefore I don't know how to stub/mock it.

Comment: I assume you're using Babel since this is ES2015 syntax. It looks like sinon doesn't support mocking dependencies like that, you might need [babel-plugin-rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-rewire) to shim a mock. Was reading [an issue](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6748) about sinon on the babel bugtracker which led me to that.

Comment: Yeah, I use Babel with the es2015 preset. I'll add that to the post.

Comment: Basically, instead of monkeypatching `service` with a mock, `babel-plugin-rewire` should let you replace `service` with something else--in this case, a mock object. It's a subtle distinction, but since you're importing `service` instead of injecting dependencies, you need to replace what gets brought in by `import * from 'service'`